# Modify Tag Command

Tags: macros, equations

Fairly sure this is something really obvious.

Trying to redefine the `\tag{...}` command via:

```
\let\tagOld\tag
\renewcommand{\tag}[1]{\tagOld{#1$^*$}}
```

In other words, it appends an asterisk to the argument, however, it is making no difference.

If I create a whole new command:

```
\providecommand{\mytag}[1]{\tag{#1$^*$}}
```

and call the new the `\mytag{...}` command instead of `\tag{...}`, then the output is generated as anticipated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\tag` itself gets redefined depending on the context but `amsmath` uses the macro

```
\def\maketag@@@#1{\hbox{\m@th\normalfont#1}}
```

to set the tag so you just need

```
\makeatletter
\def\maketag@@@#1{\hbox{\m@th\normalfont#1$^*$}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks. So how exactly is this command protecting itself from being redefined?

Comment: @ADP it isn't it is just that the top level tag command is defined each time within the alignment (usually twice, with different definition on the first pass) eg ` \let\tag\tag@in@align`  when/if it finally gets round to actually  typestting some text it calls `\maketag@@@` to typeset the box with the tag. So a top level redefinition of `\tag` has no real affect as each environment resets it back.

Answer (score 6):

The [`mathtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package provides handy tools for this:

```
\newtagform{<name>}[<inner format>]{<left>}{<right>}
\renewtagform{<name>}[<inner format>]{<left>}{<right>}
\usetagform{<name>}
```

So you can easily define `\newtagform{starred}{(}{$^*$)}` and say `\usetagform{starred}`. This could be reverted at any time by saying `\usetagform{default}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% also loads `amsmath'

\newtagform{starred}{(}{$^*$)}
\usetagform{starred}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
 E \neq m c^3 \label{eq:stupid}
\end{equation}

See equation~\eqref{eq:stupid}

\end{document}
```

[image]