# Align/Aligned/etc Tags without Parenthesis?

Tags: math-mode, align, tags

I am using `pdfLaTeX`. I am trying to use an align-like environment, and I wish to place a `\blacksquare` on the last line where a `\tag` would be.

The problem is that `\tag` automatically comes with parentheses, i.e. (). The following is what I am working with:

```
\begin{align*}
A \setminus (B \cup D) & = A \cap (B \cup D)^C\\
& = A \cap (B^C \cap D^C)\\
& = A \cap B^C \cap D^C\\
& = A \cap A \cap B^C \cap D^C\\
& = A \cap B^C \cap A \cap D^C\\
& = (A \cap B^C) \cap (A \cap D^C)\\
& = (A \setminus B) \cap (A \setminus D). \tag{$\blacksquare$}
\end{align*}
```

Is there a simple way to do this without the `\tag` having the parentheses? Thanks in advance.

Comment: this question and both answers don't mention anything about this being included at the end of a proof.  if a proof is involved, the answer would be different.  (not trying to "force"anything -- it's probable that you didn't intend this to be associated with a proof; just a caution.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116087/121799).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% also loads `amsmath'
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newtagform{noparen}{}{}
\usetagform{noparen}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
A \setminus (B \cup D) & = A \cap (B \cup D)^C\\
& = A \cap (B^C \cap D^C)\\
& = A \cap B^C \cap D^C\\
& = A \cap A \cap B^C \cap D^C\\
& = A \cap B^C \cap A \cap D^C\\
& = (A \cap B^C) \cap (A \cap D^C)\\
& = (A \setminus B) \cap (A \setminus D). \tag{$\blacksquare$}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For me this worked perfectly, and if one wishes to return to normal tagging, one can use \usetagform{default}, as in the aforementioned post

Comment: @cwr Thanks, I was just about to add this to the answer, but now it's in your comment - even better ;-)

Comment: @cws coinsider Texnicians answer instead, no extra packages

Comment: @daleif I tried to remove my answer but this is not possible as long as it is accepted.

Comment: You'll probably need to wait for the op

Comment: Hi, I have upvoted the other answer, however, this answer was provided sooner, and was the method I ended up using. So, I will keep this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

A very simple version: Use `\tag*`. So you could easily use "normal" tags within that align too.

[image: tag*]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
A \setminus (B \cup D) & = A \cap (B \cup D)^C\\
& = A \cap (B^C \cap D^C)\\
& = A \cap B^C \cap D^C\\
& = A \cap A \cap B^C \cap D^C\\
& = A \cap B^C \cap A \cap D^C\\
& = (A \cap B^C) \cap (A \cap D^C)\\
& = (A \setminus B) \cap (A \setminus D). \tag*{$\blacksquare$}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```